# Issue while migrating jersey API from WAS8.5 to WAS9

Tags: jersey, websphere, websphere-9

I am trying to migrate jersey API from WAS 8.5 to WAS 9.

While starting application in WAS 8.5 Jersey is getting initialize properly as below:

```
Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib  
  /WEB-INF/classes
ScanningResou I   Root resource classes found:
  class panaceaCSGLaction.api.cust.CustResource
  class panaceaCSGLaction.api.party.PartyResource
No provider classes found.
Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.4 05/24/2017 03:20 PM'
```

But, while staring application I am getting below error:

```
FFDC Exception:java.lang.RuntimeException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init ProbeId:181 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl@fd7e7ae6
java.lang.RuntimeException: Initialized Extension not found.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtensionFromBeanManager(CDIExtension.java:240)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1375)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:449)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
```

I am using below jersey libraries :

jersey-servlet-1.19.4.jar
jersey-server-1.19.4.jar
jersey-core-1.19.4.jar
jersey-bundle-1.19.4.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
jersey-client-1.19.4.jar